# Foreign Keys to tables where primary key is not clustered index

Tags: foreign-key, primary-key, clustered-index

I'm focusing on SQL Server here, but I think this is a database agnostic question, really.

I have a table whereby a Guid is logically the primary key.  However, uniqueidentifiers apparently make terrible clustered indexes, so I'm planning on creating a dummy key as an identity column and making that the clustered index for the table.

When it comes to foreign keys referencing this table however, should the foreign keys reference the clustered index or the primary key?  I'm thinking it should be the primary key still, right?  And that's because the clustered index doesn't technically HAVE to be unique, whereas the primary key does...?

Also, just to double check, if I make another column the clustered index, that doesn't mean I need to add a non-clustered index to my primary key column, does it?  In other words, does my column automatically have an index on it just by being the primary key?

Comment: Why do you need a `GUID` and an `IDENTITY` column? Can you not just use an `IDENTITY` column as a `UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX`?

Comment: Ideally I would use the GUID column as the clustered primary key for the table, but this can apparently lead to performance problems (unless newsequentialid() is used, but I can't use this function in Azure).  The suggestions online all seem to be to create a dummy column and make that the clustered index for the table.  Making it an identity column as well would guarantee uniqueness (identity & auto-incrementing columns are the same thing...right?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the MSDN article on [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464(v=sql.105).aspx)

> A FOREIGN KEY constraint does not have to be linked only to a PRIMARY
>   KEY constraint in another table; it can also be defined to reference
>   the columns of a UNIQUE constraint in another table.

I think it is perfectly fine to define a `UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX` on an `IDENTITY` column and define the `PRIMARY KEY` on different columns, often with a `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` but you don't have to specify an index.

Comment: Hmm...does this mean in my scenario above the foreign key is better suited against the clustered index or primary key?  Presumably if the foreign key references the primary key, an additional lookup to the clustered index is required, which means putting it against the clustered index would yield better performance...no?  If the foreign key references the clustered index, it can go straight to the row?

Comment: I would reference the `IDENTITY` column rather than `GUID`. If you put it against the `GUID` the `CLUSTERED INDEX` will need to be accessed anyway to retrieve any additional columns from your table.